# c# Visual Studio ...adding references programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

Is there anyway that a reference can be added to a solution programmatically?

I have an add-in button, when the user presses it, I want a reference to be added.

The reason is, I have created a piece of software that I want to be integrated into any given VS program (if the developer wants it), they would simply click the add-in button and the reference would be loaded in the current solution.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this I haven't tested it

get the environment

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 pEnv = null;
Type myType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.8.0");          
pEnv = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)Activator.CreateInstance(myType, true);
```

get the solution.

```
Solution2 pSolution = (Solution2)pEnv.VS.Solution;
```

get the project that you want

```
Project pProject = pSolution.Projects[0];
```

add the reference

```
pProject.References.Add(string referenceFilePath);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an example on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/addrefvsnet.aspx).

The functionality is contained within a single class `elRefManager` and the method to call is `CheckReferences`. The code can be looked at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=11658) by selecting the elRefManager.cs file on the left hand side.

As seen in the article you could do...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    int ec;
    ec=elRefManager.CheckReferences(null, new string[] {textBox1.Text});

    if (ec<0)
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred adding this reference");
    if (ec>0)
        MessageBox.Show("Could not add " + textBox1.Text + 
                    "\nCheck its spelling and try again");
}
```

Comment: This is directly related to what Darren is asking for.  He is asking how to add a reference to a project programatically from an *add-in* meaning he has access to the DEV instance/solution/project system.  He is *not* asking how to load an assembly dynamically at run time.

Comment: I will say you should indicate where in the article Darren can look at the code to figure out how to integrate it into his add-in (this is an external program which accesses the running object table and then interfaces with the same interfaces an add-in would).

Answer (score 1):

[`System.Assembly.load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx) Allows you to call functions in a library that were not built with your program.

---

If you want to add a reference to the project so that its in the solution you can use the following. Basically the same as @Scots answer.

I did it in a macro which is vb but I'm sure you can get the idea

```
    DTE.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate()
    Dim objProject As EnvDTE.Project
    Dim i As Long
    i = DTE.Solution.Projects.Count
    For Each objProject In DTE.Solution.Projects
        If (objProject.Name() = "csCA") Then
            Dim vsproj As VSLangProj.VSProject
            vsproj = objProject.Object
            vsproj.References.Add("C:\Users\test.dll")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Why the down vote?? It's ***exactly*** how you load plugins without using third party libraries. `Assembly.Load` and then `Activator.CreateInstance`

Comment: This will not add the reference to the solution, it will simply load an `Assembly` for the running code.

Comment: Some people are just weird! I've upvoted it- thanks for the response.

Comment: Daniel DiPaulo: What do you think that adding references at runtime will do (when it comes to addins)?

Comment: @jgauffin: Adding a reference and loading an assembly are two *completely* different things.  Darren is asking how to add a reference, not load an assembly.

Comment: Adding a reference is simply telling the complier to do this for you when the file is built.

Comment: @rerun: Yes, that's if you are using the compiler from the command line.  If you are using the project system/MSBUILD, it means that you have to update the project file as well.  Either way, it doesn't involve System.Assembly.Load at all.

Comment: @casperOne - if it accomplishes the same job and solves the problem at hand, then what's the point of bickering over semantics?

Comment: I originally took the question as how do I in effect add a reference to a file that was already built.  Yes I agree it will not add the project to the solution.  Which is why I went and wrote a macro to do so.

Comment: @mellamokb: That's the problem, the results are *not* the same, so semantics are irrelevant here.  The question refers to an add in which is loaded into VS, and wants the add in to add a reference to the project which is being developed.  This *is not* something that is happening at run time.

Comment: @mellamokb: Check the third comment on the question itself, Darren indicates that is exactly what he wants (to add a reference to a project when his add-in, loaded in VS has a button clicked on it).