# Error Id: CS0234, Error: The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography'

Tags: c#, ide

I am using an online IDE (http://www.frosthawk.net/) to run my C# code and upon compilation I get the error

Error Id: CS0234, Error: The type or namespace name 'Xml' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography' (are you missing an assembly reference?), Line: 26, Column: 36

Can anybody tell me how to add this reference to my code whicle using the the online IDE as I cannot right click and Add Reference that we used to do normally

```
    using System;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;

    public class SignVerifyEnvelope
    {

     public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
    try
    {

     ......
```

Comment: What's with the link to this in your original title? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410258/c-sharp-visual-studio-adding-references-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you missed this:

> //   IMPORTANT How-To-Use:
>
> //     # Add/Manage References by clicking the 'References' link
>
> //     # Manage Your Build Settings by clicking the 'Settings' link

Click references and fix your reference.

If you are unsure which reference you require, you may need to browse MSDN for help. For reference here is the  [System.Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.aspx) namespace.