# How to add dependency reference programmatically

Tags: c#

Anyone knows how can I add a dependency reference programmatically in C#?

The think is I am already generating a new project programmatically, but I need to add some references to that project.

Is it possible to do it programmatically?

Thanks.

Comment: How about adding these dependencies to the .csproj?

Comment: Compile the project and load the dll?

Comment: Adding to the csproj file will be a good option. But there is another way?

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410258/c-sharp-visual-studio-adding-references-programmatically

Comment: @user2521713, adding them programmatically really means modifying the XML of the `.csproj`. That's what Visual Studio does. But you're not in the context of VS, so you just need to add them.

Comment: @wilso132, thanks, just what I was looking for.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Scott's answer here: [c# Visual Studio ...adding references programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410258/c-sharp-visual-studio-adding-references-programmatically)

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 pEnv = null;
Type myType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.8.0");          
pEnv = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)Activator.CreateInstance(myType, true);

Solution2 pSolution = (Solution2)pEnv.VS.Solution;
Project pProject = pSolution.Projects[0];
pProject.References.Add(string referenceFilePath);
```